# change xfce panel launcher icon size

Tags: xfce-panel

I have a panel size of 24 pixels and am trying to make xfce feel like gnome2. Just the launcher icons appear to be like 14,14 when I would want them 22,22 or thereabouts. Does anyone know where to set this?

Answer (score 4):

Try right click on panel => panel preferences and changing the row size. This should automatically resize the icons in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings Editor, and look for GTK IconSizes, Click on Edit, and change it that way

[image]

You would Edit IconSizes, and in the value field, you would enter `gtk-menu 22,22`, and  then you have to restart to see the changes.

[image]

Comment: I had found this option, however I don't know with which string to address the launcher icons in the panel

Comment: See additions in the answer.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to be the right string to address them, the icon size is unchanged.. I appreciate the screenshots though :) I did try a number of other strings to address those launcher icons with but maybe you can name a few you'd try?